# Is a question about HVAC filters on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

It's just about effectiveness generally. It's not strictly home improvement is why I ask.

Comment: Could you add specifics about the question you'd like to ask? We have an [tag:air-filter] tag with 29 questions, and [116 questions that mention them](http://diy.stackexchange.com/search?q=air-filter+is%3Aq), so yours may well be on-topic as long as it's not something like "Is brand _X_ better than brand _Y_?". If you haven't already, take a look at the [help/on-topic] for a guideline as to the types of questions we want.

Answer (score 1):

I would say yes.  It is just another tools used in a house.  As long as you were comparing specs and not brands it would be just like 100s of other questions asked here.  Air filters are all about specs so this should be really easy.